# Games from gamejolt.com aren't permitted to run

Tags: technical-issues, windows-7

Whenever I run a game from http://gamejolt.com, Java prevents me from playing it.
It tells me Java doesn't allow applets without an approved certificate.  From what I understand, GameJolt's games are self-signed, meaning the creators signed their own games.

Downloading the game seems to fix it sometimes. Adding GameJolt to Java's security exceptions didn't work either.

Why won't Java let the applet run? What can I do to fix this?

I'm using Chrome on Windows 7.

Comment: What are your Java Security settings?

Comment: They're defaulted to "High" right now.

Comment: Try dropping them down (if you can), see if that makes a difference

Comment: Um... "High" is the lowest I can put it...

Comment: That's Java 8 for you...

Comment: Possibly try installing an earlier version of Java (I know for a fact 7.51 has a "Medium" security setting, though later versions of Java 7 may also). The only downside is it may be completely incompatible.

Comment: Risking security holes for video games... yep, sounds legit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chrome has dropped support for NPAPI plugins (Unity, Java, Silverlight self signed certs effected). 
You can re-enable NPAPI (but as of Sept 15 this will no longer work) :

**Enabling NPAPI in Chrome Version 42 and later**

As of Chrome Version 42, an additional configuration step is required to continue using NPAPI plugins.

In your URL bar, enter:

1. chrome://flags/#enable-npapi
2. Click the Enable link for the Enable NPAPI configuration option.
3. Click the Relaunch button that now appears at the bottom of the configuration page.

This is only effecting Chrome so another way around it is to just logon to the site with Firefox, iExplorer etc.

More info [here](http://java.com/en/download/faq/chrome.xml)